# Merging Mercurial conflicts on command line?

Tags: shell, mercurial, ssh

OK I am connected to a server via SSH, I run the command:

> hg merge

I am now taken to a screen that is split into 3 sections. On the bottom they are labeled as:

1. file
2. file~other.Dcyqtz
3. file~base.N64J4dp

Obviously it wants me to resolve conflicts. It looks like the first one is my local changes, other is the changes I just pulled and am trying to merge with. And base is what the file looked like before splitting.

So for every part where there is a conflict I supposed I am to pick which of the 3 to keep.

How do I do this?

I am in a command shell so I can not click on anything. I can only move my cursor up and down in the first of the 3, I do not know how to get my cursor to the other 2 sections.

I do no know know how to specify, use mine here, use other there, and use base over there.

Also I do not know how to say, I give up and exit.

So currently I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you need is a [merge tool](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeProgram)

**UPDATE:**

Of course you may want to use SSH with [X11 forwarding](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Displaying_Ubuntu_Linux_Applications_Remotely_%28X11_Forwarding%29)

Answer (score 3):

As Cesar mentioned, you need a [merge tool](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeProgram). If you are familiar with vim, I suggest [vimDiff](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergingWithVim).

Also, don't worry, you didn't lose any data or did anything wrong.
Just setup some merge tool, use `hg update -C` to start from clean slate. Proceed with `hg merge`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it opened in vimDiff. I am actually not familiar with vim (I always use nano) so I am trying to struggle through the tutorial you listed. I have 3 buffers open, local, other, and base. Do you know how to close the base buffer. The Tutorial says to do so but it doesn't say how. Thanks.

Comment: If you are not familiar with vimDiff, I suggest Ceaser solution to use X11 forwarding, and graphic interface, e.g. Meld. For quiting vim, press Escape, afterwards type `:exit`

Comment: Yeah, `vi` or `vim` is like the worst default editor to open with, it’s completely incomprehensible for anyone except heavy unix users.

Answer (score 1):

I am stumbling over exact same situation, usung KUbuntu 11.04.
(And me once was used emacs, not vim. So looking at those 3split console was surprising for me, too.)

Now I did `hg rollback` and installed me merger gui tool **KDiff3** .
Then looking into "howto get this gui merger tool activated within the hg merge?"

> hg help merge

Tells me what to do...

> which kdiff3

/usr/bin/kdiff3

So I added to `~/.profile`

```
export HGMERGE="/usr/bin/kdiff3"
```

Then all was done.
In a new shell `hg merge` popped me up with the gui merger tool **KDiff3**, see handbook-pdf http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/kdiff3_de.pdf